# Index performance while doing insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I have a table with 4 columns and I have 3 indexes on this table:

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].CustomerInfo(
        ID [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        UserHashID [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
        ShippingID [int] NOT NULL,
        Received [bit] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_CustomerInfo_ShippingID] ON [dbo].[CustomerInfo]  (  [ShippingID] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_CustomerInfo_UserHashID] ON [dbo].[CustomerInfo]  (  [UserHashID] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_CustomerInfo_UserHashIDShippingID] ON [dbo].[CustomerInfo]  (    [UserHashID] ASC,   [ShippingID] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I am inserting about 4-5 million records and this process takes about 45 min. I've realized that if i drop the indexes, the insert is way faster (2-3 min).

Wondering if there are any side effects by dropping the index, doing the insert and rebuilding the indexes after the insert is done. This whole process will take me maybe 5 min compared with 45 min if I have the indexes enabled.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no side effects of dropping the index, doing the insert and re-building the indexes after the insert is done (Assuming nothing else needs to access the table while you perform the insert).

This is quite a common pattern.

[That all said, I'm surprised at the time difference on a table with 4 columns and 3 indexes. Can you post your schema and index definitions]

As pointed out by @PJ8912, there may be some difference in Transaction log logging, depending on how often you backup the transaction log.

**Update**: Unrelated, but this index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_CustomerInfo_UserHashID] 
    ON [dbo].[CustomerInfo]  ([UserHashID] ASC)
```

is redundant as it is covered by this index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_CustomerInfo_UserHashIDShippingID] 
    ON [dbo].[CustomerInfo]  ([UserHashID] ASC, [ShippingID] ASC)
```

Comment: Mitch, I've added the table and index schema. Also, most of the time no other applications is accessing this table so as you mentioned, dropping the index, doing the insert and re-creating the index after the insert is done should be the way to go. However, sometimes i have two applications accessing this table. Any solution for this situation? Can i still drop the indexes, doing the insert and re-creating the indexes again? Any way i can lock this table while i do the insert? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the level of transaction logging, the TLogs could fill up with recreating the indexes regularly.  If you truncate the indexes to eliminate them, then that operation won't be logged.

The statistics for the execution plans may not be up-to-date after the new indexes are created.  You may want to update statistics with FULL SCAN mode.

Comment: "The statistics for the execution plans may not be up-to-date after the new indexes are created" - I'm not sure that's correct.

Comment: Maybe I was too quick on the draw (but there can be different settings for statistics).  My recommendation would be to see if performance is an issue and to see if the TLogs get big quickly.  I do think that dropping and creating indexes is a good practice.

Comment: statistics may not be up to date after lots of inserts that fall below the statistics update threshold.

Comment: Thanks PJ8912. I will check the settings for the transaction logs.